# PowerApps not passing variable to PowerAutomate

Tags: json, powerapps, power-automate

We have an app which is supposed to send a couple of variable to a flow for further steps. Recently I have added a new variable, which either sends "1" or "2".
When I trigger the sending of the variables in the edit mode of PowerApps, PowerAutomate receives all the variables as needed.
When I publish the App and try to do the same thing as a User, the variable stays empty. As you can see, the variable "SSW" seems not to be received by the flow or sent by the app.

[image]

Comment: looks like publish and refresh issue from powerapps, Try publish again and clear cache. Best open in different browser your powerapps and try.

Comment: Hi AnkUser;

Thanks for the suggestion, but this also did not do the trick, unfortunately.

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: Hi AnkUser,

Sorry for the delayed response. I found the "solution":
For some reason, my predecessor put the patch function not only in the trigger button I tried to get working, but also somewhere else in the app. As long as I did not change both the same way, the error uccured.
All other variables I left untouched worked, however. So I found out the solution, but not the deeper reason for the issue, unfortunately.